Can't access debugging tool in react-native
I am currently at version 0.74.0. Whenever I try to access the 'open debugger' from the dev menu from the device it throws a warning in the console

"Attempting to debug JS in Flipper (deprecated). This requires Flipper to be installed on your system to handle the 'flipper://' URL scheme."

Seems like flipper is not supported and the new devtools by react-native is not available anything below version 0.76.0. I tried to upgrade to that version but it's throwing too much dependency errors. The debugging inside VS Code is also not working.
Is there any way I could use debugging tool for the development as I need to add breaking points for checking the flow?

Please try with this command
npx react-native start --experimental-debugger

